# Listening for blur event on div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide certain div when user moves his cursor out of its bounds. I thought this should workd, but it doesn't:

```
mydiv.addEventListener('blur',function(){
    document.getElementById("logStuff").style.visibility = "hidden";
    console.log("blurred out!"); //never gets callled
});
```

This is my code to show the div I want to hide, which works:

```
mydiv.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
    document.getElementById("logStuff").style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

I would like to do this with pure js (no jquery, etc..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`blur` is for elements that can be `focused`, such as user inputs, buttons... Use `mouseout` instead.

Comment: note that the event will fire on bubbled mouseouts, if the div has any childnodes you should check the target element